# Finding probability of getting into a university based on 3 factors

Tags: probability, regression

How would I go about calculating probability of getting into a college (CU Boulder) using a data set containing GPA (0.00-4.00), ACT Composite score (0-36), Class rank percentile (0-100), and whether they got admitted (yes/no)?

For example if I was given data on 100 applicants from last year, how could I find my probability of admission?

I know it involves using regression, but I am unsure on how to do this. I have read a little about logistic and least squares.